# Can't get SQL Update to work using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, tracking, sql-update

I'm trying to get php to update a MySQL table using UPDATE statement but it simply won't work. Here's the code I wrote:

```
$add = "1";

$counter=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM frases WHERE id = '".$id."'");

while ($ntcounter=mysql_fetch_array($counter)) {    
    mysql_query("UPDATE frases SET count = '".$ntcounter[count]+$add."' WHERE id = '".$id);
}
```

As you can see, I am basically trying to update the SQL record to keep track of how many times a specific content ID was visited.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need two queries.  You should just be able to update like this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE frases SET `count` = `count` + 1 WHERE id = ".$id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias in your SQL query (*It is not mandatory, but it makes the query much more readable.*)

```
SELECT * as count FROM frases WHERE id = '".$id."'"
```

And you can now access to your variable

```
$ntcounter['count']
```

So the result :

```
$add = "1";

$id = (int)$id
$counter = mysql_query("SELECT * as count FROM frases WHERE id = '".$id."'");

while ($ntcounter = mysql_fetch_assoc($counter)) {    
    mysql_query("UPDATE frases SET count = '".($ntcounter['count']+$add)."' WHERE id = '".$id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the single quote at the end of the update statement:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE frases SET count = '".$ntcounter[count]+$add."' WHERE id = '".$id."'")
```